# Is there a way to remove the red outline from a rect?

Tags: python, image, pygame, rect

Here is my problem.

[image]

I need to get rid of the rectangle's outline but everything I tried, I can't get it off.

Here is a small, reproducible example of the code:

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()
w = h = 500
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((w, h))

image = pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load('image.png'),(64,64))

rect = image.get_rect()
rect.center = (250,250)

running = True
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            running = False
    
    screen.fill((225,225,225))
  
    screen.blit(image, rect)

    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255,0,0), rect, 1) # I can't get rid of the rect because I will be moving and manipulating the image with my mouse so it has to stay for future code changes.

    pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
```

As you can see when running the code, the image has a small red outline around it. I tried to set the outline width to 0 but then it just covers the entire image with red. Is there a way to get rid of it?

Comment: Remove `pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255,0,0), rect, 1)`. This is the red outline

Comment: That won't work because I need to draw the rect to be able to move it with my mouse later on.

Comment: You don't need to draw the rect (`pygame.draw.rect`). All you need is `rect`. But there is not any reason to call `pygame.draw.rect`